# Wio 3G SORACOM　での　WDT（ウォッチドッグタイマ）等のリセットについて

Tags: c++, soracom

https://soracom.jp/products/module/wio_3g_soracom_edition/
上記ボードで、loop()処理を使い、
扉の開閉や定期的な温湿度計測をしているのですが、時々フリーズしてしまう為、
WDT（ウォッチドッグタイマ）等による適宜のリセットを検討しております

ただ、arduinoで一般的な　avr/wdt.h は利用できないようで・・・、
なにか有用情報ありましたら、お教え頂きたく、よろしくお願いします

Comment: フリーズの原因を調べて、フリーズしないようにするのが良いのではないですか？　問題を放置すると、思わぬところでトラブルを起こしますよ。

Comment: ありがとうございます　原因究明にも努めます